# Compare classes extending the same superclass

Tags: java, polymorphism, equals

Consider we got a class `MyEntity` which has some field with getters and setters. Furthermore the classes `EntityA` and `EntityB` extend `MyEntity`. There are some fields in `MyEntityA` that are not in `MyEntityB` and vice versa. As we are talking about entities, `EntityA` and `EntityB` do have their own `equals`-methods looking like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((this == other))
        return true;
    if ((other == null))
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof EntityA))
        return false;
    EntityA castOther = (EntityA) other;

    return ((this.getId() == castOther.getId()) || (this.getId() != null && castOther.getId() != null && this.getId().equals(castOther.getId())));
}
```

This `equals`-method is neded for hibernate to identify the unique entity.

Now I want to compare an instance of `EntityA` with an instance of `EntityB`. I define them to be identical, if all the fields from `MyEntity` match.

To check this I let eclipse generate the equals method for me and copy it to a method like `isEqualWithRegardsToContent(MyEntity other)`.

I see one big problem with this approach:
If someone ever adds a new column to either one of the entities and doesn't update the `isEqualWithRegardsToContent(MyEntity other)`-method, it get's buggy: The entities might be considered as equal with regards to content, although they aren't.

I don't see that a unit-test would help here.

Do you have any best practices?

Comment: why can't you leave `equals()` in superclass only, so subclasses could use it interchangeably?

Comment: If equality depends only on the base class's attributes, why do you need subclass `equals` methods?

Comment: @Chris311 Are the IDs different types? If they are the same type and both subclasses have it, why not move the ID to the superclass (assuming it has the same logical meaning for both, i.e., identifying the entity uniquely)?

Comment: This does not work due to different sequenceGenerators and columnNames.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou When adding a new subclass EntityC, this entity does not need to override equals(). You must modify the equals method in the superclass then, which one might forget.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hibernate needs this equals-method for comparison, in order to save or update an entity. The id is defined at entity level.

Comment: @Chris311 If the comparison is based only on common attributes (=attributes in `MyEntity`), then adding `EntityC` won't have any impact on it, whatever is contained in `EntityC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you have `equals()` method in superclass that compares common properties.

In subclass `equals()` you can first call `super.equals()`, then, if compared object is also of this class, compare only specific properties. So in `EntityA` you write:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean eq = super.equals(o);
    if (eq && o instanceof EntityA) {
        EntityA e = (EntityA) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.propOne, e.propOne) 
            && Objects.equals(this.propTwo, e.propTwo)
            && // compare other properties
    } else 
       return eq;
}
```

Such, objects of the same concrete class will be compared by full set of properties, including common and specific properties, and instances of different classes will be compared only by common properties. Though this is non-standard way which violates *transitive* property of the contract, it may solve your particular problem.

Comment: This has one big issue: entityA.equals(entityB) != entityB.equals(entityA)

Comment: @Chris311 no, this is not the issue. `entityA.equals(entityB)` will compare based on only common properties (by `super.equals()`), and vice versa.

Comment: Ok, but still: What to do if someone adds a field to the `MyEntity` and forgets to update the equals-method?

Comment: @Chris311 there is no universal solution. You may collect all declared properties by reflection and use them in `equals()`. Or require properties upon which equals is built, to be annotated with some annotation and write this in JavaDoc for implementors,  etc

Comment: Now I found out what is the issue here. Consider you call entityA.equals(entityA). This won't check the fields inside entityA.

Comment: It will, indeed. `eq` will be true (because common properties are equal) and `if` block will be entered and also return true.

Comment: Let us make this a little bit harder. Consider EntityA has a column columnA with FetchType.Lazy. EntityB has the same column but you don't want it to be fetched lazy. How to solve this problem? You can't put it in the abstract class then, can you?

Answer (score 2):

generally speaking its impossible to have a fully functioning equals when dealing with inheritance trees. `superclass.equals(subclass)` will not return the same result as `subclass.equals(superclass)`, breaking symmetry (which is the basic contract for equal - if `a.eq(b)` then also `b.eq(a)`).

you could implement equals() only at the top level, thereby comparing the entire hierarchy from the point of view of the superclass. this will work, but will not compare by "all fields" (only those in the superclass). commonly entities may be compared by just their primary keys

personally i dont usually mix the 2 - `equals()` and `hashcode()` i reserve for simple data-storage classes (or keys used to lookup in maps) that are not polymorphic.

see a details coverage here - http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals-2.html

Comment: I agree. My solution would be to implement equals / hashcode on the leaf classes of the inheritance tree

Comment: And if anyone adds a field to the superclass and forgets to update the equals-method?

Comment: @Chris311 - thats a general problem when maintaining code that has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Those entites are 99% the same and you don't think inheritance is the way to go here?

Comment: @Chris311 - i was just saying that keeping equals() up to date w.r.t changing fields is a problem even if you dont add inheritance. generally i wouldnt use equals() here though, maybe some ValidationService.isAlreadyDefined(Entity) method to check if there's an "equivalent" other entity in existence. such a service could get around most of the issues equals() would run into - being aware of all the subclasses and not having to maintain symmetry

Comment: Ok, but this would only shift the problem to another class.

Comment: How could the service avoid issues equals would run into?

Comment: @Chris311 - 1st of all an external service does not have to adhere to the equals() contract, where as a non-compliant equals() is confusing and dangerous (if other people use your code). 2nd an external service could compare different subclasses without breaking symmetry (running into a.eq(b) != b.eq(a)).

Answer (score 0):

A class' `equals()` method should only work for other instances of that class. If you want to compare `EntityA` and `EntityB` with `equals()`, then your `equals()` method should be defined on `MyEntity` (along with `hashCode()`) and both `EntityA` and `EntityB` should not have `equals()` methods themselves. Otherwise, you are very likely to run afoul of the [contract for `equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). Libraries such as Hibernate depend upon `equals()` properly adhering to the contract.

Comment: That is exactly what I did: The entities themselfes have equals-methods for hibernate purposes (Id is defined at entity-level). The superclass has the method isEqualWithRegardsToContent.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem:

- you have a class named `MyEntity` lacking a `getId` field
- you have 2 subclasses `EntityA` and `EntityB` both defining a `id` field but form different generators
- when comparing 2 objects of class `EntityA` (resp. `EntityB`) they compare equal if and only if their id fields have same value - I assume that in that case all fields inherited from `MyEntity` have same value
- when comparing a `EntityA` object with a `EntityB` one, they should compare equal if and only if all the fields inherited from `MyEntity` are equal.

Here is what you could do:

- declare an `equals` method in `MyEntity` that returns true if and only if all fields compare equal - if you cannot use the `equals` method for that, name the method `ABequals` (for example)
- declare the equal method in subclass `EntityA` (resp. `EntityB`)

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if ((this == other))
          return true;
      if ((other == null))
          return false;
      if (!(other instanceof EntityA))
          return MyEntity.equals(other);  // or return ABequals(other);
      EntityA castOther = (EntityA) other;

      return ((this.getId() == castOther.getId()) || (this.getId() != null && castOther.getId() != null && this.getId().equals(castOther.getId())));
  }
  ```

In that case you **must** implement a hash method in the `MyEntity` class that uses all the fields and you should not overide it in subclasses. That way you ensure that two objects that compare equal will have same hash value - the above definition already guaranties that the `equals` function is an equivalence relation.

Comment: you can simply delegate comparison of common properties to `super.equals()`, no need to repeat them in concrete class

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: If both objects are of same class this method only compares their id.

Comment: Oh, now I see. This long line confused me

Comment: Why do I have to implement the hash method in `MyEntity`? What if I would not do that?

Comment: @Chris311: Because the Javadoc for `Object` class requires the following contract for `hashCode` method: *If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result*. If you do not respect this, you could get incoherent result for example when searching an object in a container.